# calling java methods from java script

Tags: java, javascript, jetty

I am trying to create a light weight web interface using

embedded jetty to host the server,
and a simple html code with a java script to display the main page, since the pages are not static depending on a condition I would need to make a call to a java code. The sample html code is as follows :

```
 <body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function myfunction(frm)
{
  var opt=frm.option.value;
  alert("option is"+frm.option.value);
   // call a java method depending on the value of opt
  frm.option.value="";
 }
</script>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Agent Management Interface</h1>
    <ol>

    </ol>
    <form name="management_form">
            Enter Option: <input type="text" id="optiontb" name="option">
            <input type="button" onclick="myfunction(this.form)" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure if this question has been posted earlier but I am wondering is there a method to pass a variable to a user defined java code and obtain return values and display them on the web interface?

I read around a little bit I am not using any external tool, developing using eclipse, using applets is not an option. I would like to the web interface as light weight as possible.

Edit 2:

I have updated the html file with the suggestions as given below, but this does not seem to be working for me. I suspect it is because of the way I have written the handlers, the log messages are :

```
2012-05-28 16:02:53.753:DBUG:oejs.AsyncHttpConnection:async request (null null)@16471729 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@fb56b1
2012-05-28 16:02:53.754:DBUG:oejs.Server:REQUEST / on org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$SelectChannelHttpConnection@bc8e1e@127.0.0.1:8080<->127.0.0.1:47830
2012-05-28 16:02:53.756:DBUG:oejs.Server:RESPONSE /  304
2012-05-28 16:02:53.757:DBUG:oejs.AsyncHttpConnection:async request (null null)@16471729 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@fb56b1
```

The code written for the handlers is as follows

```
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.DEBUG","true"); 
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
    resource_handler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
    resource_handler.setResourceBase(args.length == 2?args[1]:".");
    resource_handler.setWelcomeFiles(new String[]{ "index.html" });
    System.out.println("serving " + resource_handler.getBaseResource());

    ContextHandler context0 = new ContextHandler();
    context0.setContextPath("/senddata");
    Handler handler0=new HelloHandler();
    context0.setHandler(handler0);

    ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();
    contexts.setHandlers(new Handler[]{context0});

    HandlerCollection handlersc = new HandlerCollection();
    handlersc.setHandlers(new Handler[]{resource_handler,new DefaultHandler(), contexts});
    server.setHandler(handlersc);
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what is happening? Also, if there are stack traces, can you please include those as well?

Comment: @jmort253 - oops sorry about that , I forgot to mention what was happening, localhost:8080 loads the text and button, when I type say 1 and click on the submit button I do not see any change in the web page, but only the log messages in the eclipse console.

Comment: ok. Debugging 101. First, make sure you're doing something in your Handler that will print something to the log. `System.out.println("Hello world!!!");` is a very quick way to do that if you don't have logging setup.  Second, check your NET tab in Firebug or Chrome debugger and look at the server response, see if it contains the Hello world the server is returning in `response.getWriter.println()`. In other words, you're at the point where you need to narrow down the problem by figuring out where the disconnect is.

Comment: @jmort253 yup i debugged it and found that the issue, was the new DefaultHandler() too which was included in the set of handlers, I assume that there are priorities assigned to the handlers and they get executed with a specific priority once i got rid of that, it's working fine now. the tip about the chrome debugger and Firebug was very handy too

Comment: Great to hear! :) And the debuggers, please continue to explore those. They will become very loyal friends to you as you continue working with them ;)  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique that you're looking for is AJAX. Since JavaScript is client side code and Java is code that runs on the server, the only way to get data to or from the server is to make an HTTP request to the server to request the data.

Below is an example from the [Mozilla Developer Center page on Getting Started with AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  // this is the function that will make the request to the server
  function makeRequest(url) {
    var httpRequest;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } 
      catch (e) {
        try {
          httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {}
      }
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }

    // here we set the onreadystatechange event to invoke "alertContents"
     // this is called when the response returns. This is a "callback" function.

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);

    // this starts the send operation
    httpRequest.send();
  }

  // here is the callback handler
  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {

        // since the response from the Jetty server is <h1>Hello World</h1>
         // the alert should fire with that markup
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);

    } else {
      alert('There was a problem with the request.');
    }
  }
}

// this is your function, with the makeRequest call. 
function myfunction(frm)
{
    var opt=frm.option.value;
    alert("option is"+frm.option.value);
    // call a java method depending on the value of opt
    frm.option.value="";

    // call makerequest here with your data
    makeRequest('/senddata?value=' + frm.option.value); 
}

</script>
```

While the above code will allow you to make the HTTP request from the browser, you'll need a servlet in your Java application in order to receive the request, process the request, and return the response back to the browser.

The [Embedded Jetty site has an example of how to create a Handler](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty#Hello_World_Handler), which you can use to examine an HTTP request, process it, and return a response. I modified the example slightly to extract a query parameter that you would pass in through the AJAX request:

```
public class HelloHandler extends AbstractHandler
{
    public void handle(String target,Request baseRequest,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        // the value passed in from the client side
        String value = request.getParameter("value");

        // do stuff with that here

        // return a response
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);

        // this gets sent back down to the client-side and is alerted
        response.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    }
}
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Thanks! I've been doing this non-stop for weeks! My goal was to hit it before June 1st :)

Comment: @jmort thanks a ton for this, but this code does not seem to be working for me. I will edit the question with the findings

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call Java Methods within Javascript.

Java being rendered on the server side, and javascript on the client side (web-browser mostly)

Both, don't have any knowledge about each other.

The best you can do is call any JSP or servlet or whichever applicable, through a link or a form submission or AJAX, that in turns calls the particular Java method for you.

Comment: 1. actually, you can call java from javascript on the client* 2. java can be a client language (applets). javascript can be a server language (node.js)

* http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure @linuxeasy was referring to the context in the OPs question :) ie "using applets is NOT an option".